# Variable not assigning on void Start() (noob question)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a code to make a cube move back and forth within a certain range of it's original placed position.

The script is directly on the cube and it does move, but around 0,0,0 coordinates, not it's original position.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ObstacleResonator : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float xspeed = 0f;
    public float yspeed = 0f;
    public float zspeed = 0f;

    public float xrange = 0f;
    public float yrange = 0f;
    public float zrange = 0f;

    float StartX;
    float StartY;
    float StartZ;

    Vector3 desiredPosition;
    void Start()
    {
        // this is what i think is the problem, the variables are not getting assigned
        float StartX = transform.position.x;
        float StartY = transform.position.y;
        float StartZ = transform.position.z;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        // the following is to make it reverse once it is out of range in any of the axes
        if (transform.position.x > xrange + StartX)
        {
            xspeed = -xspeed;
        }
        if (transform.position.x < -xrange + StartX)
        {
            xspeed = -xspeed;
        }


        if (transform.position.y > yrange + StartY)
        {
            yspeed = -yspeed;
        }
        if (transform.position.y < -yrange + StartY)
        {
            yspeed = -yspeed;
        }


        if (transform.position.z > zrange + StartZ)
        {
            zspeed = -zspeed;
        }
        if (transform.position.z < -zrange + StartZ)
        {
            zspeed = -zspeed;
        }

        // the following actually moves the cube
        desiredPosition.x = transform.position.x + xspeed * Time.deltaTime;

        desiredPosition.y = transform.position.y + yspeed * Time.deltaTime;

        desiredPosition.z = transform.position.z + zspeed * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = desiredPosition;
    }
}
```

There probably is a more compact way to write it.

The cube is moving around 0,0,0 instead of it's original transform position. I tried assigning the StartX, StartY, StartZ values manually, and it worked perfectly, but they just dont seem to get assigned by on the start.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you declare NEW variables within the Start() function, they go out of scope as soon as the function is executed. You don't update the class variables.

Use this instead:

```
void Start()
{
    StartX = transform.position.x;
    StartY = transform.position.y;
    StartZ = transform.position.z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much you saved me hours of googling

Comment: Always read the code you write carefully. And watch out with coping & pasting code....

Comment: @GlebMarkovski Don't forget to accept the answer if it fixed the issue.